# How to protect my API key in android app?

Tags: android, api, key, piracy

I'm developing an android app and using some of Google APIs which requires API key.

I'm paying for the API. How to protect my Key from piracy?

Comment: you have to enable proguard, check this link
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html